# ASIHTTPRequest with Put issues & kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

Im trying to upload a file from the Document folder to URL using ASIHTTPRequest 
     put method. I'm getting the following error which seems to be kCFErrorHTTPParseFailure error . Any Idea what is the issue and how it can be fixed ?

```
 Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred"
 UserInfo=0xe027890 {NSUnderlyingError=0xe026300 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)", NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure 
 occurred}

 My code as follow 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.uploadURL/"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
[request addBasicAuthenticationHeaderWithUsername:@"UsrName"
                                      andPassword:@"UserPassword"];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
 request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection   = NO;

[request setPostBodyFilePath:fullPathFile];
[request setShouldStreamPostDataFromDisk:YES];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Im just trying why im getting that error And the way to do it correctly .

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077284/what-is-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-code-303)

Answer (score 1):

okay I did figure it out . The following code is for Using HTTP put to upload a file. Hope that will help someone.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.SomeSite/UploadFolder/FileName.ext"];
 ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
 [request addBasicAuthenticationHeaderWithUsername:@"UsrName"
                                       andPassword:@"UsrPassword"];
 [request setShouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge:YES];
 [request setDelegate:self];
 [request setAuthenticationScheme:(NSString *) kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic];

 [request setPostBodyFilePath:fullFilePath]; // Example: Documents/MyFile.txt
 [request setShouldStreamPostDataFromDisk:YES];
 [request startAsynchronous];
```